# Implementing Non Content Sites

Tags: cloudscribe

Can we use ClouldScribe for non-content scenarios like Classifieds Posting?

Planning to develop a Classifieds Posting web application. Here I want to use cloudscribe's engine and another part (like add posting, listing, search) I will write on my own.Is it possible with cloudscribe or its overkill of cloudscribe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cloudscribe Core for management of users, roles, claims etc and then build custom features for anything you need.

The idea is for cloudscribe to provide some things so you don't have to build them yourself, ie user management and role and claim management, so you can focus on what you want to build, ie classified posting application.

cloudscribe puts no limits or constraints on your development approach. You could also use cloudscribe SimpleContent for marketing/information pages of your site if you need that, but you can use cloudscribe Core without using SimpleContent if you don't need that.